# Variable template in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need two functions to bind at two buttons. They are so similar and only one string is different.

```
const onClickLoginA = (): void => {
  const loginURI = `http://.../.../A`;

  window.open(loginURI, `Login with A`);
}

const onClickLoginB = (): void => {
  const loginURI = `http://.../.../B`;

  window.open(loginURI, `Login with B`);
}
```

In C++, I can write these in

```
template <string str>
void onClickLogin()
{
    const string uri = "http://.../.../" + str;

    system("open " + uri);
}
```

Is there any simple way to merge these two functions in one without any parameter with Typescript?

---

## My solution

```
function onClickLogin(target) {
  return () => {
    const loginURL = `http://.../.../{target}`;
    window.open(loginURL, `Login with {target}`);
  }
}

const onClickLoginA = onClickLogin(A);
const onClickLoginB = onClickLogin(B);
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://tsplay.dev/N9pJ9w ?Please keep in mind that `suffix` should be mutated in this case. I think it worth using function argument

Comment: Wow... simple... lol

Comment: Can you invoke `window.open()` directly from those buttons? `<button onClick={()=>window.open(`http://.../.../A`, `Login with A`)}>Login with A</button>`

Comment: @DancingCat if my solution works for you, I can provide it as an answer

Comment: [Factories](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAZEBzAlmAEsmACYA2i8MAvDABRjIC2iAXDNPHlgDQwCunNhy4BKagD46ItgDcQOYhJgBvAFAwYAdzzEQmgHQgADojC0BOXgANMuMFpxQAFjAAkyhswC+Vkaq+qqqCQsOAAwqQ4wADWtngAgtRwSKgY2HiEJOTwtADk8bm8uU5QUEYsAPQV+jXVtQV+wdAw4ZExcWAAQkkIKGgdmWQUeZ2FMMWl5VU1+nWzoyJAA) would be easier to manage than a mutable variable

Comment: @captain-yossarian it works! Answer please. I'll accept it

Comment: There are so many way to do this! I found it Interesting.. Thanks to all 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```js
let suffix = 'A'
const onClickLoginA = (): void => {
    const loginURI = `http://.../.../${suffix}`;

    window.open(loginURI, `Login with ${suffix}`);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzgrgZnAlgDwgXggcgIKYFADGA9gHZSSkDCwiBA1gDJEDmiJ26EAFAJQBcEAG5FEAE3QA%20CAG88EeRGJlIwFmwCqAJQCSnAAYALMGAAOfAPTmAdDeu2AJNNgIUAXz0BuPHIUB3NqJEvlZEJiAkXKqsJFraADQQekzREP5gBhCOzkjI7jxernhAA)

If you are ok with using global variable, you can stick with this solution. Otherwise I would suggest you yo use `suffix` as an argument.

I assume `onClickLoginA` is a callback/event handler on a button. If you want to provide an argument to a callback, you can use this approach:

```js
<button onClick={()=>onClickLoginA('A')}>
```

ot you can `curry` your function:

```js
const onClickLoginA = (suffix: string) => () => {
    const loginURI = `http://.../.../${suffix}`;

    window.open(loginURI, `Login with ${suffix}`);
}
<button onClick={onClickLoginA('A')}>
```

Aboce examples are common patterns in `react`.